# Получить дату за последние сутки javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
let d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1);
```

Таким образом я получаю последние 24 часа. А как мне получить дату, начиная с 00.00 текущего дня?

Comment: обычно день начинается с 00 часов 00 минут 00 секунд, и сегодняшний день — не исключение (да, в истории имеется несколько исключений). поэтому суть вопроса, мягко говоря, не совсем понятна.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var d = new Date()

d.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)
console.log(d.toISOString() + "\n" + d.toString())

d.setMinutes(-d.getTimezoneOffset())
console.log(d.toISOString() + "\n" + d.toString())

var d = new Date()

d.setHours(0, -d.getTimezoneOffset(), 0, 0)
console.log(d.toISOString() + "\n" + d.toString())
```

Comment: пояснения к ответу не требуются тому, кто и сам может ответить на вопрос. но такому знатоку ведь и сам ответ не нужен. так для кого же тогда предназначен ответ без пояснений?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, для того, кто не может внятно сформулировать вопрос. Если одна из дат - это то, что он хотел, то разберётся. Ну а уж догадаться, что третье делает то же самое, что первые два, но в одно действие, вполне реально по выводу. PS: Кстати, я не так уж давно узнал, что в setHours можно передавать не только часы.

Comment: `для того, кто не может внятно сформулировать вопрос` — окей, принимается: образец ведь даже имеется (в виде автора **данного** вопроса). но это всего один человек. а как насчёт всех остальных, у кого может возникнуть подобный вопрос, и кто сформулирует его поисковику по-своему, пусть тоже невнятно, но по-своему невнятно? что получается: в вопросе невнятная формулировка, в ответе **вообще** нет ни одного слова (кроме имён функций и синтаксических конструкций языка программирования), т.е. поисковики не помогут. ответ ради всего одного человека?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, писать гайд по таймзонам и объяснять, чем один результат отличается от другого - то ещё удовольствие. А весь ответ по сути сводится к "используй метод `setHours`" и искаться должен как раз по вопросу, а не по методу из ответа.

Comment: 1. между «писать гайд» и «не писать ничего» — огромное море возможных вариантов. стоит ли в оправдание одной крайности приводить другую? 2. если конкретно про данный ответ, то, насколько вижу, в вопросе вообще-то нет ни слова про таймзоны. а первые две-три строчки можно было ведь и комментарием написать. но раз уж выбрана более удобная для демонстрации форма — в виде ответа — то отчего бы и не черкнуть пару слов. вроде «таймстемп для начала суток можно получить с помощью такой-то функции». ну а в довесок и про таймзоны, конечено, можно упомянуть (с отсылкой в википедию, например).